# Default copy constructor for a class without data members and brace syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, list-initialization

Consider the following class definition:

```
class A { };
```

That is, `A` is a class without *data members* (even though it doesn't have *function members* either).

The following code work as expected because the compiler generates both the *default constructor* and the *default copy constructor* for the class `A`:

```
A foo;
A bar(foo); // calls A's default copy constructor
```

However, if the *brace syntax* is used instead of the parenthesis. The code doesn't compile:

```
A foo;
A bar{foo}; // ERROR
```

On GCC 4.9.3 I get the error:

> too many initializers for 'A'

By doing any of the following points, the last code snippet does work:

- Adding a *data member* to the `A` class definition.
- Explicitly defining a *copy constructor* in the `A` class definition (not even by using `= default` works). Of course, the *default constructor* has also to be defined after doing so for the code above to work, because it is not generated by the compiler any more.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Probably GCC issue that got fixed in 6.1, where [it compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/meE2An).

Comment: @Zereges Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Zereges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087601) suggests in his comment, the issue why the code is not compiling is a **bug** in GCC.

This bug is fixed in GCC as of version 6.1 and the code compiles as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this example to compile when using gcc 5.1, but only when using c++14, which you can enable by using the -std=c++14 flag.

Looking at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
you can see in the examples:

```
S s1 = { 1, { 2, 3, {4, 5, 6} } };
S s2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; // same, but with brace elision
S s3{1, {2, 3, {4, 5, 6} } }; // same, using direct-list-initialization syntax
S s4{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; // error in C++11: brace-elision only allowed with equals sign
                        // okay in C++14
```

So this seems to be a c++14 feature.